# Caching issue with Javascript Stepcarousel in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm using the Stepcarousel Javascript plugin from this link : [Stepcarousel](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm)
I have 20 separate html pages that contain some html codes : divs and paragraphes that I'm loading using the `JQuery.load()` method into the stepcarousel as panels so for each forward/backward click I'm  loading the content of an html page into the stepcarousel it's working like a slider that loads and shows html content on each forward/backward click.

The issue I'm facing is that everything is working on Firefox and Chrome but in IE9 it's working too however while I'm at at the panel 15 it is starting to show things like if many html pages are loading at the same time, I think it's about caching in IE9 but I tried everything and that bug is still happening.

This is the html code I'm using:

```
<div id="divCarousel" class="stepcarousel">
   <div id="panel1" class="panel"></div>
   <div id="panel2" class="panel"></div>
   .....................................
   .....................................
   <div id="panel20" class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the function I'm using to load the html content from a separate html page and display it on the stepcarousel :

```
function fncToPage(vintPage) {/*vintPage is the number of the panel that the carousel goes to when I click on the forward button*/
   $("#panel"+vintPage).load('HTMLContent/page'+vintPage+'.html');
}
```

Can you please tell me what can I do to make this bug desapear in IE9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is caching issue then try adding a random-number or timestamp as a dummy query string to the page url you loading with AJAX to force browser not to use cached copy

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I did as you suggested : `$("#panel"+vintPage).load('HTMLContent/page'+vintPage+'.html?_='+ Math.random()*99999);` It's as before working on FF, chrome but same bug in IE9

Comment: Try to put that sample online so we can see it.. or Use IE9/10 developer tools to see what requests are taking so long..

May be your testing webserver is unable to handle too many requests at the same time.. Test IE after you close FF and chrome